# create search function to support wildcard char only when it is input by user

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm writing a function to search (case insensitive) through CSV files. To test this I'm using an array, and user input to check the array. I only want the search to include a wildstar if the user inputs a wildstar and the position of it matters too.

For example (in pseudo code), given the `$array = "Hanna", "Anna", "Ann"`

```
if userInput = Ann
output = "Ann"

If userInput = Ann*
output = "Ann", "Anna"

if userInput = *nna
output = "Anna"

if userInput = *nn*
output = "Hannah", "Anna", "Ann"

if userInput = *Hanna*
output = "Hanna"

if userInput = Hanna
output = "Hanna"
```

and so forth...

I'm using a CSV file `test1.csv`:

```
test1Column1,test1Column2,test1Column3
Hannah,12345,
Anna,1234,
Ann,2345,
```

I have the following code:

```psh
Function SearchContentName
{
    Param ($userSearchContent)

    If ($userSearchContent -Contains '`*')
    {
        Import-Csv test1.csv | % {if ($_.test1Column1 -Match $userSearchContent){$_.test1Column1}} | Export-Csv testresults.csv -NoTypeInformation
    }
    ElseIf ($userSearchContent -NotContains '`*')
    {
        Import-Csv test1.csv | % {if ($_.test1Column1 -Eq $userSearchContent){$_.test1Column1}} | Export-Csv testresults.csv -NoTypeInformation
    }
}

Function Main
{
    $userSearchContent = Read-Host "Enter Name"

    SearchContentName $userSearchContent
}

Main
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong operators. Since you want to allow wildcard matches, simply use `-like` for all user input:

```
Function SearchContentName {
    Param ($userSearchContent)

    Import-Csv test1.csv | ForEach-Object {
        if ($_.test1Column1 -like $userSearchContent) {
            $_.test1Column1
        }
    } | Set-Content testresults.csv
}
```

The `-match` operator is for regular expressions, where you'd have to express "any number of characters" as `.*`, not just `*`. The `-like` operator behaves like `-eq` if `$userSearchContent` doesn't contain wildcard characters, so you don't need to distinguish between different cases.

If you want the output CSV to contain whole lines and headers, use `Where-Object` instead of filtering with an `if` nested in a `ForEach-Object`:

```
Function SearchContentName {
    Param ($userSearchContent)

    Import-Csv test1.csv | Where-Object {
        $_.test1Column1 -like $userSearchContent
    } | Export-Csv testresults.csv -NoType
}
```

Comment: with this code and my input of `Ann*`, the output is blank when it should include the rows of `Ann` and `Anna`. Any idea why?

Comment: @FiddleFreak Your function doesn't return anything, but writes the data back to another CSV. However, since you're output is strings rather than objects `Export-Csv` will export the properties of the string objects (`Length`) rather than the actual strings. Either use `Where-Object` instead of the `ForEach-Object`/`if` combination, or export the data via `Set-Content`. See updated answer.

Comment: Ah okay, seems to be working great. Let me run a few more tests then I'll give you the check as the answer. Yup, perfect, so I guess i should start becoming more familiar with like/contains/eq/match and their counterparts.

Comment: @FiddleFreak See [`about_Comparison_Operators`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847759.aspx).